# How to parse coordinates to get only those that belong to a certain country?

Tags: php, json, gps, maps, coordinates

i have a JSON file that contains lon and lat coordinates.
I want to parse this file and then create a new JSON file that contains only coordinates of a certain country.

Is it possible to do this? How to figure out what country the coordinates belong to?

Comment: You would probably need a polygon for the boundaries of the country and then you could do a simple point in poly lookup. Or you could probably do something with the google maps geocoding api.

Comment: Where can i get a list of coordinates of the boundaries? What is poly lookup?

Comment: I don't know, google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broad strokes, it sounds like you want to do what's called [reverse geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding).  This is the process of taking a known set of coordinates and getting an address from it.  The address would include the country.

Depending on the size of your data set, [Google offers one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) that might suit you.  You could write a routine to iterate your data set, reverse geocode each set of coordinates, and get a structured address (including country), which you could cache for future use.  With the countries, you could then filter the list down to the specific country you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What API key i have to request for?
There are a lot of "Google Maps" services... is "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" the right one?

Comment: Solved, the right API was "Geocoding API"... thank you.